# jQuery .text() method returns turns into NaN in other function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to modify prestashop mobile navigation and 've got some difficulties 
trying to append sub categories lists with new elements containing main category title. The title gets written as NaN.
 **Code:**

```
$('#maincategories > li').children('a').each(function() {

        //here i remove original navigation icons so they wont get into title String.
        $(this).children('span').remove();
        var str = $(this).text().toString().replace(" ","");

        var generateSubmenuTrigger = function(action) {
            if (action == 'show') {
                var triggerClass = 'showSubnav',
                var parentTitle = "";
            } else if (action == 'hide') {
                var triggerClass = 'hideSubnav';
                var parentTitle = str;
            };
            return '<a class="msubnav '+ class +'">'+
                       +parentTitle+
                   '</a>';
        };

        $(this).parent('li').append(generateSubmenuTrigger('show'));
        $(this).parent('li').children('div').children('ul').append(generateSubmenuTrigger('hide'))
    });
```

I've been checking `parentTitle` string using console.log and it all was good until i push it inside my `generateSubmenuTrigger` function. It would be really nice if someone could explain why it becomes into NaN and how to fix it.

Comment: define 
var triggerClass 
var parentTitle

outside if condition

and also in  'return '<a class="msubnav '+ class +'">'+
                       +parentTitle+
                   '</a>';
replace class with triggerClass

Comment: bout the parentTitle  in return line, have missed it when rewriting some classes before post the questions. thanks for advice, gonna try it now.

Comment: Add required html.

Comment: I'm more than sure that issue is in mine code above. but gimme a sec. This html gets generated via javascript or jquery because when view port > 768px there's no mobile navigation html in DOM at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is in this return statement:

```
       return '<a class="msubnav '+ class +'">'+
                   +parentTitle+
               '</a>';
```

You have two pluses in between the `a` tag and the `parentTitle`. Remove one of them.

By the way, I don't see `class` defined anywhere. Take note that naming a variable `class` can cause to unexpected behaviour also as it is a reserved word in JS.

I would also replace the`$(this).text().toString()` with `$(this).text()` as the `.toString()` is useless anyway.

Comment: Thanks, all 's good now. Class there's no 'class' variable in production, I've messed up some variable titles while refactoring code before asking a question. And this .text().toString() was just to make sure it gets saved as string, bcus this NaN got me bad.